# Minimization with Trace of Hadamard Product

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-decomposition, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have the following minimization problem, where I want to find $ X $
$$
\min_{X \succeq 0} \mathrm{tr}(A X) ~~~ \mathrm{s.t.} ~ X \circ I = I
$$
Assume that $ A $ is Hermitian positive definite, $ I $ is the identity matrix and $ \circ $ is the Hadamard product.

**Solution**:
The Lagrangian is given by $ L = \mathrm{tr}(A X) - \mathrm{tr}(U \cdot (X \circ I - I)) - \mathrm{tr}(V X) $, where $ U,V \succeq 0 $ are the KKT multipliers. Computing the derivative w.r.t $ X $ yields:

1. $ A - U \circ I - V = 0 $

In addition due to KKT complementary conditions:

2. $ U \cdot (X \circ I - I) = 0 $

   $ V X = 0 $

Any hints how to continue? I do not see any useful relations.

Comment: Should the complementary condition be "=0"?

Comment: Corrected. Thank you!

Comment: What do you think about the first condition ($ A - U \circ I = 0 $) when the off-diagonal elements of $A$ are nonzero?

Comment: From the first condition, only that $ A_{ii} = U_{ii} $. Now, for the off-diagonal elements there are no restrictions as long as $ A $ is positive definite.

Comment: I disagree on that. Part of $A - U \circ I = 0$ is $A_{12} = 0$. Simply put: the derivative of your Lagrangian w.r.t. $X$ cannot be $0$ for many choices of $A$.

Comment: You are right! Nice catch.

Comment: The solution is now trivial, right? Postmultiply the first condition with $X$ to get $AX - (U\circ I)X = 0$, so $\mathrm{tr}(AX) = \mathrm{tr}((U\circ I)X)$. Can you simplify $(U\circ I)X$? What is the diagonal of $X$?

Comment: I have post-multiplied the Lagrangian by $ X $ and I get that $ \mathrm{tr} (AX) = \sum_i U_{ii} X_{ii} $.

Comment: were you eventually satisfied by my answer?

Comment: Is there a complete solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The first KKT condition is called "dual feasibility". It represents the set $\{U : \min_{X \succeq 0} L(X,U) > -\infty\}$. Only if $X$ is unrestricted in sign you can simply set the derivative to $0$. Let me show it for LP duality on this problem:
$$\min_x \{ c^Tx : Ax\geq b, x\geq 0\}.$$
If you use:
$$L(x,y)=c^Tx + y^T(b-Ax)$$
the set $\{ y :\min_{x \geq 0} L(x,y) > -\infty\}$ is characterized by $c-A^Ty \geq 0$ (because if the derivative w.r.t. $x_i$ is negative, you can let $x_i$ go to $\infty$ and the value of $L(x,y)$ will go to $-\infty$).

On the other hand, if you use
$$L(x,y,z)=c^Tx + y^T(b-Ax)-z^Tx$$
the set $\{ y :\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} L(x,y) > -\infty\}$ is characterized by $c-A^Ty-z = 0$. Since $z\geq 0$, these conditions are the same.

Going back to your semidefinite problem, the first approach is difficult because elementwise reasoning no longer applies. If you consider the condition $X \succeq 0$ as a constraint (and add an extra term in the Lagrangian), then you can just set the derivative to $0$.

Comment: I missed the positive definiteness constraint on $ X $ in the Lagrangian...

Comment: You did not miss it, it is possible to formulate the KKT conditions without it. The problem was that you mixed the two approaches.